# How to remove trailing slashes from URL with .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

### The situation

Across the entire domain, we'd like the URLs to *hide file extensions* and *remove trailing slashes*, independent of the domain name itself (as in, works on any domain).

### Sample of our directory structure

We're not using index.* files except for the homepage.

- /

  - /index.php
  - /account.php
  - /account

    - /subscriptions.php
  - /login.php
  - /login

    - /reset-password.php

### The goal

Some examples of how these files might be requested, and how they should look in the browser:

- `/` and `index.php` --> `mydomain.com` (literally just the bare domain name).
- `/account.php` or `/account/` or `/account` --> `mydomain.com/account`
- `/account/subscriptions.php` or `/account/subscriptions/` or `/account/subscriptions` --> `mydomain.com/account/subscriptions`

As you can see, there are several ways to access each webpage, but no matter which of the 2 or 3 ways you use to get there, it only shows the one preferred URL in the browser.

### The question

**How is this done with .htaccess using mod_rewrite?**

I've banged my head against the wall trying to figure this out, but in general, the rewrite flow would seem to be something like this:

1. External 301 redirect ( `mydomain.com/account/` --> `mydomain.com/account` )
2. Internally append .php ( `mydomain.com/account` --> `mydomain.com/account.php` )

I've been Googling this all day, read thousands of lines of documentation and config texts, and have tried several dozen times... I think more brains on this would help a lot.

## UPDATE

We found an answer our question (see below).

Comment: How would you differentiate between account.php and an account/ folder? That's what the trailing slash is for.

Comment: Good question. They are the same thing. The "account" folder rewrites to "account.php". (You'll often find this structure in Visual Studio web projects.)

Comment: Huh? I'm sorry, that doesn't make sense to me. If there's an /account.php file, and an /account/index.php file (normally accessed simply with /account/) how do you differentiate between the two? On a filesystem, they are *not* the same thing.

If you're bootstrapping everything through a single index.php folder, like PHP frameworks do, then maybe that make sense. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. We won't be using index files (except the homepage; but don't worry about that for this question). All the filenames are descriptive of their contents. This means, for instance, that `/account/` will rewrite to `/account` and actually deliver `/account.php`, *not* `/account/index.php`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for your time to look at the question, but we appeared to have figured it out:

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

# rewrite /dir/file?query to /dir/file.php?query
RewriteRule ^([\w\/-]+)(\?.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L,T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

We have to turn off Multiviews and Indexes so the engine doesn't get confused and instead try to reference any `index.*` file or show a directory listing (also confusingly called an "index" with Apache...) when a directory appears to be requested.

The first redirect visibly (`R=301`) removes the trailing slash, and the second one internally rewrites it to the PHP (or HTML, etc.) file at hand.

This .htaccess file also supports query strings.

**Update** As noted in the comments below much earlier, we've switched to nginx, and this is all our conf file contains related to URL-rewriting (from my dev box):

```
location = / {
    index index.html;
}

try_files $uri $uri.html =404;
```

We've also switched from PHP to just plain HTML, but changing the extensions above should hardly make a difference, if at all.

Comment: In hindsight, we've switched to nginx and this whole task was SUPER-easy...

Comment: Minor point, but you don't need to escape the forward slash (`/`) in the regex, as it carries no special meaning. `\/` is the same as '/'.

Comment: @w3d Good point. That's a habit from my Javascript regex'ing.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to redirect /account to /account.php? In fact, the page /account only exists with [Content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). If you don't want it, just disable the directive.

About your two rules, I think it is straightforward:

```
RewriteRule ^/account/$ /account
RewriteRule ^/account$ /account.php [R,L]
```

It is untested, however. You can also add `[R,L]` to the first line, in this case, the browser will make one more redirect.

Comment: In theory, that's the general idea (except we don't want to display .php in the browser), but that would only work for account.php. We're hoping for a general solution that works throughout the site. Using refiddle to test our regex's,  we *know* that regex's like `^(.*)/$` indicate URLs with a trailing slash, but that only seems to have effect in top-level directories, not subdirectories. (Requests to subdirectories re-write with full server path in the URL and show it in the browser for some reason.) We're also certain that `^(.*)[^/]$` indicates a URL without a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a flexible and simple way to route URL requests for your website or app, I would recommend a PHP micro-framework. Not only will you have complete control over your URL routing, but it will provide other benefits as well.

I've used the [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) before, combined with the [Symfony Templating Component](http://components.symfony-project.org/templating/) with great results. If I were to do it again, I would probably just use the [Silex Micro-framework](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), since it's also a part of Symfony Components.

Comment: We thought about something like this (thanks for the links), but our development version of the site is PHP-powered and the deployed production site is 100% static (no PHP). This .htaccess file will be fore the deployed production site.

Comment: It would be very easy to quickly create a static site based on these micro-frameworks. The project I used them for was mostly static content, with just a splash of PHP used to bootstrap the site using the micro-framework. Depending on the size of the site, converting it to use a micro-framework might be faster than banging your head against .htaccess all day.