# Remove multiple trailing slashes in a single 301 in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, trailing-slash

There is a similar question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess?rq=1), but the solution does not work in Apache for our site.

I'm trying to remove multiple trailing slashes from URLs on our site. I found some `.htaccess` code that seems to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

This rule removes multiple slashes from anywhere in the URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories////
becomes
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories/
```

However, it redirects once for every extra slash. So:

```
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories///////
301 Redirects to
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories//////
301 Redirects to
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories/////
301 Redirects to
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories////
301 Redirects to
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories///
301 Redirects to
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories//
301 Redirects to
http://www.mysite.com/category/accessories/
```

Is it possible to rewrite this rule so that it does it all in a single 301 redirect?

Also, this above directive does not work at the root level of our site:

```
http://www.mysite.com///// does not redirect but it should.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the slashes may only occur at the end of the URL, you may use this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(?:/){2,}$
RewriteRule . $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think you mean `%1` (back reference to the RewriteCond pattern) in your RewriteRule, rather than `$1`? As it stands you will always be redirected back to the document root. Also, I'm curious as to whether `(?:/)` is required in the RewriteCond, can you not simply use `/`?

Comment: yes, sorry force of habit in that syntax. The $1 is ok, but you can omit the (?: ) and use only /

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about how this works?   A code only answer is only helpful with some exlaination.

Comment: It's exactly what I need and the only one it works for me. Perfect!