# Removing trailing slash for sub directory url indexing

Tags: web-hosting

I have a site with multiple different sites in sub-directories. I want to view the sub directory in two formats.  For example:

1. `www.example.com/blog`
2. `www.example.com/blog/`

Both should show the index page under blog folder.

After turning DirectorySlash off, redirection is off from `www.example.com/blog` to `www.example.com/blog/` but in `www.example.com/blog`, all contents of that folder are showing instead of the index file.

Comment: I have tried this
===================
#Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex index.html 
Options -Indexes
==========
I am getting 403 forbidden error for example.com/test
But it is working fine for www.example.com/test/

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990838/remove-trailing-slash-from-sub-directory-folder-apache-1-3-42-directoryslash-off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want better now.   Let me recap:

- `/test` should show the contents of `/test/index.html`
- `/test/` should redirect to `/test`
- `/test/index.html` should redirect to `/test`
- `/test/something.html` should show its own contents

You can do this with the knowledge that I gained by asking about how to do something similar here: [How to rewrite to a script and also redirect away from that script using .htaccess while avoiding infinite loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15340785/1145388)

This is what you can put in `.htaccess` that should work for you:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test$ /test/index.html [L,E=LOOP:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^test/$ /test [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^test/index.html$ /test [R=301,L]
```

I tested this on my server, it satisfies all the conditions that I outlined above when I have a `/test/` directory containing the files `index.html` and `something.html`

Comment: Thank you very much stephen, it is working for me.Now, I am going to apply other rules in this folder. I am very grateful for your kind help.

Comment: Extremely sorry Stephen for late. I have checked you answer. Thanks again a lot!

Answer (score 2):

DirectorySlash off is a funny one to be honest because often I can't get it work and I just use this plain old simple rewrite condition which does the job just superbly.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

An alternative method using DirectorySlash Off can be found here [Pro Webmasters - How to remove trailing slashes from URL with htaccess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

**Disable Directory Browsing with Virtual Host Config Files**

You can disable the directory listing in the main config in your apache setup like so:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you do not have access to this file i.e your using a shared web host then add the following to your htaccess file:

```
 Options -Indexes
```

Comment: I have tried the first one.
=====================
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
================

But it is automatically adding slash when browsing with www.example.com/test.

But, I dont want this redirection. I want to show index.html file under test sub folder when trying both the follwing urls.

www.example.com/test
and www.example.com/test/

Comment: So you want it to be example.com/test/index.html? If so then you are removing it via index.html -f... for the sake of people answering please could you edit your question and list everything you have in your .htaccess file

Comment: Can you please suggest me the coding how can I keep www.example.com/test only. When ever, any one will browse www.example.com/test/ , it should then show www.example.com/test url. But www.example.com/test/somepage.html will work fine.

Comment: You really need to edit your question. Your adding things that was not originally asked in your question.

Comment: I will do it. But, Can you please answer my question if you can

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what your asking - Hence I asked to edit your question. Currently its borderline in being closed since what you've asked has been asked before check the comment at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Which file is shown as the default page in a directory is controlled by two settings in Apache.  These settings can either be set in the `httpd.conf` file or in a `.htaccess` file.

```
# DirectoryIndex controls which file is chosen as the default page in a directory
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php welcome.html

# The Indexes option controls whether or not a file listing is shown.  
# This usually takes effect only when a DirectoryIndex file cannot be found.
# -Indexes turns off the file list, +Indexes turns it on.
Options -Indexes
```

Based on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258879/apache-directoryslash-off-site-breaks it appears that `DirectorySlash Off` has the side effect of preventing `DirectoryIndex` from working.

Comment: Good point, the best method for him is most likely disable directoryIndex and then use a conditional rewrite for removing the tailing slash.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer,. But, it is not working for me.
I have written the following coding in the inner folder.
========
#Options -Multiviews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex index.html 
Options -Indexes
========
It is giving 403 forbidden when I am trying 
www.example/test

But, www.example.com/test/ is working fine. Please do kindly help

Comment: Stop using `DirectorySlash Off`.

Comment: Also, you could edit your post to say exactly what you want to happen at each of `/blog` and `/blog/`.  Which do you want to show the index document?  Which do you want to redirect?

Comment: DirectorySlash Off removing is redirecting www.example.com/test
to www.example.com/test/.

But I dont want this. 
I want www.example.com/test will display content same as www.example.com/test/ without redirecting in url

Comment: So you want both `/blog` and `/blog/` to show the content directly with no redirecting?

Comment: yes,I dont want to redirect both the two url.
I want to view the index.html file under test subfolder by using 
www.example.com/test and www.example.com/test/

Comment: For search engine optimizaton (SEO) purposes, you usually want to make sure you have a single canonical URL.  I would suggest using redirects instead of showing the same document at two different URLs.  `DirectorySlash On` does the correct thing for SEO.  What is the reason that you don't want a redirect?

Comment: yes, I do agree with you. Then,Can you please suggest me the coding how can I keep www.example.com/test only. When ever, any one will browse www.example.com/test/ , it should then show www.example.com/test url. But www.example.com/test/somepage.html will work fine.

Comment: Can you please help me on that.