# Duplicate title tags error in webmaster tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, duplicate-content

I have changed some URLs in my site then to prevent webmaster tools duplicate error I **redirected (301)** old URLs to new URLs also I tried to remove old URLs in "**Optimization>Remove URLs**" section of webmaster tools and still I get Duplicate title error.

I want to know is any problem in redirecting?

For example 
http://www.visakga.com/visa redirected to http://www.visakga.com/visa-and-residency

PS,
I used **Fiddler** to check 301 redirect and think it should be okay.

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML Improvements Last updated Mar 25, 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess and say HTML Improvements may of updated on the 25th March but that doesn't necessary mean the data they used is from 25th of March if that makes sense. I would say if you got the 301 redirects set there is no way there is duplicates and hopefully on the next update it should resolve itself.

One thing I have noticed is that you do not have [rel="canonical"](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps) set on your pages, some and including myself class this as one of the most important tags for avoiding duplicates. This would of avoided this situation furthermore I hope you don't mind but I also found that your website is access with and without tailing slashes for example:

1. `http://www.visakga.com/visa-and-residency`
2. `http://www.visakga.com/visa-and-residency/`

Notice how URL 2 has the tailing slash, sadly I've had problems with people back linking with trailing slashes and this has caused duplicates. So you could use canonical on your pages and never worry about things like this again, or alternatively if you rather not use a canonical solution then you can remove [tailing slashes using the htaccess file](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess).

Comment: As you noticed I've add `rel="canonical"` and fix tailing slashes, Now I'm waiting to apply changes, Thank you for response.

Comment: What about "Optimization>Remove URLs" why doesn't affect? this feature needs more time too?

Comment: Once you've done a 301 you shouldn't manually remove any URLs since Google will correct the problem without any further invention. Personally I think its a bad idea to remove pages because you don't know if your losing any weight on them.. Do a 301 in future then in HTML improvements mark the problem as fixed.. but do not remove urls...

Comment: I didn't remove any pages, I just use Web master tools Remove URLs to prevent checking by Google crawler, Now should I re-include removed URLs?