# Redirect to the correct URL without trailing slashes

Tags: url, 301-redirect

My correct URL is `http://mydomine.com/cars/register.php` (without slash in the end).

But I send emails to our customers with wrong URL `http://mydomine.com/cars/register.php/` (with slash in the end).

Customers cannot access the page correctly.

How to re direct them to the correct URL when they click on the wrong link?

Comment: Your host has cPanel installed? You can do that using cPanel

Comment: Why dont you send the correct url?

Comment: This might help :  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/how-to-remove-trailing-slashes-from-url-with-htaccess?rq=1